# Completable future & Executor service and Java EE or application server - etier

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-8, ejb, executorservice, completable-future

I am creating flood of async tasks and  executing them with the help of completablefuture supply async by passing custom executor service with the thread pool that i created.

In tomcat i don't have to do anything specifically to manage the executor or task completion stage.

The question is do i need to worry about e-tier runtime environment like weblogic ,websphere app servers since am explicitly creating threads rather getting them 4m Managed Executor service ?

How does jvm manages common fork pool in etier and web tier environments??

And also could you please share any references to know more about e tier explicit thread management in case of completablefutures. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing sample code in weblogic - found out that there is no need of handling / managing the normal executor service in etier unless the submitted task to the future is not accessing any jndi or other services that need container handling.  In such cases we may have to rely on Managed3xecutors. Please refer Managed Executors for more information